# Convert 24V dc to negative 24V dc

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, converter, linear-regulator

My circuit is supplied by a 24V DC generator, but I have amplifiers in my circuit that need to be supplied by 24V and -24V, so I need to generate -24V dc from the 24V that I have from the generator,does anyone has an idea how to convert 24V to -24V,thank you for helping.

Comment: The LT circuit that Andy Aka shows in his answer is a CUK convertor  which is a accepted way of making a negative rail.Many basic colleges dont teach this .

Comment: Usually the op amps use +/-15V small current.

Comment: How much current will you need?  There are inverting charge pumps.  (24V is hard.... LTC3260?)

Comment: @oussama  How much current at -24V do you need to generate?

Comment: @NickAlexeev I need to supply an amplifier (LT1014), for example in the datasheet of LT8330 i found 1A, but 1A means the maximum current right?? I can connect the output of LT3880 to supply the LT1014 right ??

Answer (score 1):

Try an inverting switch mode regulator like the LT8330: -

[image]

Or you can use the search engines provided by LT or TI. [Here's](http://www.linear.com/parametric/Inverting_Regulators#!1646_Inverting!1032_%3C=23!1033_%3E=25!1034_%3E=24!2086_%3E=49!1035_0.307:1.53!vinmin_23!vinmax_25!vout_-24!iout_0.1!vout2_!iout2_!vout3_!iout3_) a link to LT's that already has some parameters honed to your application. Please don't come back and moan about cost - if you want something cheap do some digging yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your response i don't have any problem with the cost but i need through hole regulator not a surface mount one.

Comment: Probably what you need is an isolating dc to dc converter. Try googling Traco Power. They do plenty